# Golang: How to create unknown (dynamic) Map length

Tags: dictionary, go

I can create a "static" map via

```
type m map[int]map[int]map[int]bool
```

but the length of "keys" will be dynamic:

```
 |---unknown len--|
m[1][2][3][4][2][0] = true
```

or

```
|---unk len--|
m[1][2][3][4] = true
```

How I can create this map in Go? Or any way exists?

Added: Hierarchical is **IMPORTANT**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're only doing `map[int]map[int] ... map[int]type` why are you using a map? This would be better handled by [`slices`](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_types) `[][] .. []type`

Comment: Slices not a good idea, because keys undefined. And only Maps give "not a fatal error" when try to access to undefined key.

Comment: Out of curiosity what are you doing with this?

Comment: Yes, I show in the example of words: I have two words: "help" and "hello", I can get a one map is `m[h][e][l][p] = true` and other map `m[h][e][l][l][o] = true`. If I try to another key, such as `map[h][e]` the result must be false, not a fatal error. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I had some fun playing with this a bit. Here is a much better implementation than what I did before:

```
type mymap map[int]*myentry

type myentry struct {
    m mymap
    b bool
}

func (mm mymap) get(idx ...int) *myentry {
    if len(idx) == 0 {
        return nil
    }
    entry, ok := mm[idx[0]]
    if !ok {
        return nil
    } else if len(idx) == 1 {
        return entry
    }
    for i := 1; i < len(idx); i++ {
        if entry == nil || entry.m == nil {
            return nil
        }
        entry = entry.m[idx[i]]
    }
    return entry
}

func (mm mymap) setbool(v bool, idx ...int) {
    if len(idx) == 0 {
        return
    }
    if mm[idx[0]] == nil {
        mm[idx[0]] = &myentry{m: make(mymap), b: false}
    } else if mm[idx[0]].m == nil {
        mm[idx[0]].m = make(mymap)
    }
    if len(idx) == 1 {
        mm[idx[0]].b = v
        return
    }
    entry := mm[idx[0]]
    for i := 1; i < len(idx); i++ {
        if entry.m == nil {
            entry.m = make(mymap)
            entry.m[idx[i]] = &myentry{m: make(mymap), b: false}
        } else if entry.m[idx[i]] == nil {
            entry.m[idx[i]] = &myentry{m: make(mymap), b: false}
        }
        entry = entry.m[idx[i]]
    }
    entry.b = v
}

func (m mymap) getbool(idx ...int) bool {
    if val := m.get(idx...); val != nil {
        return val.b
    }
    return false
}

func (m mymap) getmap(idx ...int) mymap {
    if val := m.get(idx...); val != nil {
        return val.m
    }
    return nil
}
```

[Playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/bwBEVKeBar)

Something like that ought to get you started

Comment: Thank you very much! Try to understand your idea. )

Comment: I don't know if it is perfectly working or if I added a bunch of stuff I didn't need, I wrote this really quickly. I think it is fairly ugly code for the record. I also don't expect it to have that good of performance.

Comment: About performance don't panic :) In the real mode it will be 40-50 iteration on every run... I try to use (concat) your code with my :)

Comment: I gave a much more sane implementation. Still no guarantees, but should get you started

Comment: Yeah ) Big Thanks! It's more useful solution! Of course, not directly ready with my code, but solution is GOOD, Really Good!

Answer (score 3):

The [map type](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types):

> A map is an unordered group of elements of one type, called the element type, indexed by a set of unique keys of another type, called the key type.

A map type must have a specific value type and a specific key type. What you want does not qualify for this: you want a map where the value is *sometimes* another map (of the same type), and *sometimes* it's a `bool`.

Your options:

#### 1. With a wrapper value type

The idea here is to not use just a simple (`bool`) value type, but a wrapper which holds both of your potential values: both a `map` and the simple value (`bool`):

```
type Value struct {
    Children MapType
    V        bool
}

type MapType map[int]*Value

var m MapType
```

This is basically what user3591723 suggested, so I won't detail it further.

#### 2. With a tree

This is a variant of #1, but this way we clearly communicate it's a tree.

The cleanest way to implement your hierarchical structure would be to use a tree, where a node could look like this:

```
type KeyType int
type ValueType string

type Node struct {
    Children map[KeyType]*Node
    Value    ValueType
}
```

This has the advantage that you may choose the value type (which is `bool` in your case, but you can change it to whatever type - I used `string` for presentation).

For easily build / manage your tree, we can add some methods to our `Node` type:

```
func (n *Node) Add(key KeyType, v ValueType) {
    if n.Children == nil {
        n.Children = map[KeyType]*Node{}
    }
    n.Children[key] = &Node{Value: v}
}

func (n *Node) Get(keys ...KeyType) *Node {
    for _, key := range keys {
        n = n.Children[key]
    }
    return n
}

func (n *Node) Set(v ValueType, keys ...KeyType) {
    n = n.Get(keys...)
    n.Value = v
}
```

And using it: 1. build a tree, 2. query some values, 3. change a value:

```
root := &Node{Value: "root"}
root.Add(0, "first")
root.Get(0).Add(9, "second")
root.Get(0, 9).Add(3, "third")
root.Get(0).Add(4, "fourth")

fmt.Println(root)
fmt.Println(root.Get(0, 9, 3))
fmt.Println(root.Get(0, 4))

root.Set("fourthMod", 0, 4)
fmt.Println(root.Get(0, 4))
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/2wVN_N-_q1)):

```
&{map[0:0x104382f0] root}
&{map[] third}
&{map[] fourth}
&{map[] fourthMod}
```

#### 3. With a recursive type definition

It may be surprising but it is possible to define a `map` type in Go which has unlimited or dynamic "depth", using a recursive definition:

```
type X map[int]X
```

It is what it says: it's a `map` with `int` keys, and values of the same type as the map itself.

The big downside of this recursive type is that it can't store any "useful" data in the value type. It can only store the "fact" whether a value is present which is identical to a `bool`-like information (`bool` type: `true` or `false`), which may be enough in rare cases, but not in most.

Let's see an example building a "tree":

```
var x X
x = map[int]X{}
x[0] = map[int]X{}
x[0][9] = map[int]X{}
x[0][9][3] = map[int]X{}
x[0][4] = map[int]X{}
fmt.Println(x)
```

Output:

```
map[0:map[9:map[3:map[]] 4:map[]]]
```

If we want to test if there is a "value" based on a series of keys, we have 2 options: either use the special `v, ok := m[i]` indexing (which reports if a value for the specified key exists), or test if the value is not `nil`, e.g. `m[i] != nil`.

Let's see some examples testing the above built map:

```
var ok bool
_, ok = x[0][9][3]
fmt.Println("x[0][9][3] exists:", ok, "; alternative way:", x[0][9][3] != nil)
_, ok = x[0][9][4]
fmt.Println("x[0][9][4] exists:", ok, "; alternative way:", x[0][9][4] != nil)
_, ok = x[0][4]
fmt.Println("x[0][4] exists:", ok, "; alternative way:", x[0][4] != nil)
_, ok = x[0][4][9][9][9]
fmt.Println("x[0][4][9][9][9] exists:", ok, "; alternative way:", x[0][4][9][9][9] != nil)
```

Output:

```
x[0][9][3] exists: true ; alternative way: true
x[0][9][4] exists: false ; alternative way: false
x[0][4] exists: true ; alternative way: true
x[0][4][9][9][9] exists: false ; alternative way: false
```

Try these on the [Go Playground](http://play.golang.org/p/qzHfuZDLar).

**Note:** Even though `x[0][4]` is the last "leaf", indexing further like `x[0][4][9][9][9]` will not cause a panic as a `nil` map can be indexed and yields the zero value of the value type (which is `nil` in case the value type is a map type).

Comment: WOW! Thank you very much! Extended explain helps me to understand Map. #3 (recursive type definition) is absolutely fantastic method. I didn't knew about recursive definition. #3 most identical with my algorithm. Thank you very much again!

Comment: Sorry, I can't click +1 (not enough "mana"), but if my idea will have commercial success I will find you and will make a present! ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the hierarchical map structure and just want to use keys with variable length one approach could be to simply use strings as keys and one single map.

```
m := make(map[string]bool)
k := fmt.Sprintf("%v_%v_%v", 1, 2, 3)

m[k] = true

fmt.Println(m[k])
```

Comment: It's my mistake, sorry... Hierarchical is **important!**.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this as this sort of type is not representable in Go's type system.

You will have to redesign.

E.g. a type `arbitrarilyKeyedMap`with a method `lookup(vals ...int) bool`.
Probably you'll need methods for setting and deletion too.

Comment: Ok, and what about solutions based on a structs? Any idea? Thanks!

Comment: That _was_ the idea. Maybe I do not understand your last question?

Comment: I can't did redesign.. All logic based on map, or, probably I can modify to structs (like Btree), but I don't know how to do this... And I ask you: do you have any idea based on struct (*Tree) solution? Important things: 1. Create/Get any depth element. 2. If element doesn't exists would return False (not a access error). Thanks.

Comment: I admit have no idea how to answer this question. Of course you **will** have to redesign as Go's map type cannot do what you need to do. And yes, this redesign probably will boil down to some kind of tree-like data structure (but hey, which problem in CS doesn't?). And yes, your code should not panic but return false. So what exactly is the question?

Comment: So sorry, probably I very bad speak in English and very bad know "Go" to be correctly ask. Below I got answer. Sorry again.